# Nuances between "ничего себе" and "надо же"

Tags: словоупотребление, значения

> **Ничего себе**, тебе удалось ...
>
> **Надо же**, тебе удалось ...

On the surface, they appear to be synonyms used to express your surprise, "wow", but how are they nuanced?

I'm assuming that you use "надо же" when something **unexpected** has happened, while  "ничего себе" is used when you are **impressed** with what someone has unexpectedly done.

The two expressions might have some overlapping uses, but I wonder if there are any instances where they are simply not interchangeable?

Answer (score 4):

"Надо же" is used with a tinge of annoyance, saying you didn't expect it to happen but it happened."Ничего себе" is more positive than the previous version. In any case, everything depends on the intonation of the person, any of these phrases can be pronounced either with a positive connotation or negative.
For example: "Надо же, тебе опять повезло" and "Ничего себе, ты поменял стрижку!"

Answer (score 4):

Ничего себе reflects greater surprise. You really express emotion, while надо же can be used without any emothion "I did not expect this, but so it happened, okay".